# ejs tags causing errors inside the script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

i am trying to use ejs tags inside an internal script tag in an ejs template.. the code works, but "vs code" still says there is a "problem"  the "<%-" and "%>" are highlighted red

```
 <form action="/posts/<%=post.id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
      <button> delete </button>
    </form>

//internal script
    <script>
      var post = <%- JSON.stringify(post) %> ; 
      mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWlsZXMtYmxhcSIsImEiOiJjazBld3NxZjEwam0wM2V0aTV0MmlreDQxIn0.rEo1aSdtmy8RL-wX4Ni3AA';
    //setting up client side mapbox
      var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
        center: post.coordinates,
        zoom: 3
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the declaration of the `post` variable like this,

```
var post = <%= JSON.stringify(post) %> ;
```

Comment: actually fixed it, the problem was because i was writing it in an internal script, and my ejs file associatiosns is "html".. so i had to add this to my settings.json "html.validate.scripts": false,".. and it worked